# Returning MultiType of a QgsWkbType

Tags: pyqgis

I want to create a new "multi" layer based on another layer. The original layer can be of any type, e.g. PolygonZ, Polygon, PolygonM, Point, LineString25D, etc. This is not pre-defined.

I can get the WKB type using

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print(layer.wkbType())
```

and set the new layer to this type.

But **how can I set the new layer to this type in multitype?**

```
layer.wkbType().multiType()
```

throws

> AttributeError: 'Type' object has no attribute 'multiType'

The [docs](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsWkbTypes.html#qgis.core.QgsWkbTypes) state

> multiType Returns the multi type for a WKB type.

I am aware that maybe not all types do have a multitype. I did not look though all the types available. In this case it can just throw back an error, e.g. via `try except`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this the following:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
wkbtype = layer.wkbType()
multiwkbtype = QgsWkbTypes.multiType(wkbtype)
print(wkbtype)
print(multiwkbtype)
```

As done in the [native promotetomultipart algorithm](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/d13a7b72787b5557860a38cdceda482a9dd4831e/src/analysis/processing/qgsalgorithmpromotetomultipart.cpp#L82).